# Pass condition to Redshift UDF's

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to implement mySQL IF function equivalent in Redshift using User Defined Function in Redshift.The syntax would be:

`IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

Is it possible to pass the condition/expression to Redshift UDF's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an expression to a UDF but you can pass a string. which you could then evaluate in python.

However, the easier way is to use the case statement

```
case {condition} then {value_if_true} else {value_if_false} end
```

the case statement is a standard in SQL (wheras IF is not)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html

Comment: I understand case when should be used but I am programmatically converting mySQL queries to Redshift.Hence, needed this.I will try the eval thing with python.

Comment: hey good luck with that! please share if you can if you can get it to work automatically!